# QtWebEngine: How to hook Ctrl + V KeyEvent?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine, libqxt

I want to call a method if the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> ("Paste") triggered.

I tried to add a new action with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> keycode. This works for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> but not for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

I tried to get the `KeyEvents` from the OpenGL Child Object of the View. Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore with Qt Version 5.9.0.

I found `libqxt`, which supports global keyevents. But it seems no longer maintained. (Website does strange redirects).

How can I add shortcuts for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to `QtWebEngine`?